# GitLab 5.0 produces Error 500 on Project settings page after creating new Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab

Last week i updated to GitLab 5.0. All previous existing projects are working fine when trying to edit them.

Today i created a new one and everything also seemed to work fine. Then i wanted to add a member to my project and checked the settings page and everything i got was An Internal Server Error (500).

The only log i've found was in production.log:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 95ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `heads' for nil:NilClass):
    36:                   .input
    37:                     = f.text_area :description, placeholder: "awesome project", class: "span5", rows: 3, maxlength: 250
    38: 
    39:                 - unless @repository.heads.empty?
    40:                   .clearfix
    41:                     = f.label :default_branch, "Default Branch"
    42:                     .input= f.select(:default_branch, @repository.heads.map(&:name), {}, style: "width:210px;")
  app/views/projects/_form.html.haml:39:in `block in _app_views_projects__form_html_haml__2678582515483350008_62614560'
  app/views/projects/_form.html.haml:17:in `_app_views_projects__form_html_haml__2678582515483350008_62614560'
  app/views/projects/edit.html.haml:6:in `_app_views_projects_edit_html_haml___3552883863573912945_62197460'
```

But what does this mean?

I already tried to recreate the project but this leads to the same error. My Gitlab installation is a default one except that i'm using unicorn with Apache Proxy instead of nginx.

*UPDATE:*
In the meantime i figured out that the repo wasn't created. The clarifies the error message but why is the repository not created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a recent [similar bug](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3155) a month ago.

> Sorry, I think sidekiq was down... I've restart gitlab and nginx -> Now it works.

so:

- check if your sidekiq is up
- if you have a really recent version of GitLab, check your [GitLab `init.d`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/tree/master/init.d) script ([which recently changed `unicorn` for `puma`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/commit/33433b655fd4de92ada68db41dbb6dd29de68160))

---

In this case, sidekiq was down, but a complete restart of the server itself was necessary for the setting page of the project to be available again.

Comment: Well you were right that sidekiq was down (it sometimes shuts down and i don't know why) but after restarting sidekiq it also doesn't work. I'm using Gitlab 5.0 and checked init script - it uses unicorn, not puma.

Comment: @mr.VVoo 5.0 still uses unicorn. Can you make more test now that your sidekiq is up? Can you shutdown and restart everything and see if the issue persists? Can you try in a new project to add a member?

Comment: In the meantime i figured out that the repo wasn't created.

Comment: i haven't created the repo on my own

Comment: @mr.VVoo I believe the repo is only created when you add at least one member to it.

Comment: Well i can't add a user since i can't access the settings page... That's at least what i want to do.

Comment: @mr.VVoo even after shutting down all processes and restarting everything? And what about creating a new project and see if the issue persists?

Comment: I do not understand why, but another restart did solve the problem.

Comment: @mr.VVoo ok. I mentioned as much in the edited answer to make that step more visible.

Comment: not a complete restart of gitlab, a complete restart of the whole system was required. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We encountered a similer problem with wrong permissions.

You should check the permissions of /home/git/repositories. Maybe the git process is not allowed to create folders/files in there.

Comment: I meant checking the ownership of the folders. Should be "git" in standard installation.